# Installing jquery in rails 7 breaks turbo

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo

I have a rails 7 app with `turbo-rails 1.1.1`. In my app `"turbo-method": :delete` works as expected for my logout delete route.

After installing `jquery 0.0.1` through `bundle add` and adding `import "./add_jquery";` to my `application.js` I get a route error for /logout.

```
No route matches [GET] "/logout"
```

It appears that jquery breaks turbo in rails 7.

Any suggestions on how to set this up properly?

Comment: `jquery 0.0.1`? that's a weird version. `bundle add` what exactly? are you using importmap-rails or jsbundling-rails?